# Is the Samsung 960 SSD 'firmware-saga' unsolvable on linux?

Tags: linux, firmware, wine, samsung-ssd

I am stuck with a Samsung 960 EVO with the 3B6QCXP7 firmware vision that causes system hangups and elusive performance problems and there are thousands of threads on the internet about it. I am on Linux, and I can't find a way to fix the problem on Linux. The confusion/lack-of-knowledge I am having is at least two-fold:

**Problems**

1. Could I downgrade the firmware? Or how would I know that it is only possible to upgrade firmware?
2. How would I actually download the firmware (from the Internet) for this particular device when I'm on a Linux machine.

**What I gather so far.**

Preliminary reading seems to indicate that (1) it is only possible to upgrade the firmware, but there is no word on why that is the case. Regarding (2) downloading the firmware from the Internet; Samsung does not provide the firmware on its website. But by reading I have found out that it could be possible to download the later version of the firmware (4B6QCXP7) using the magician software (version > 5.2). Unfortunately, 'Magician' is not available for Linux. For Linux, there is the 'Magician DC' command-line tool, but it seems it is unable to download anything over the Internet. By reading, it appears that people have been advised not to attempt firmware upgrade by Wine. This is the point where my competence stops, and I am not sure whether to bin the device, or if it is still solvable somehow.

If you know a solution, it would be good if you could provide it.

Comment: Sadly if the manufacturer tools are not supported on your system then you will have to work on a system where they are supported. Sometimes upgrades can change or modify internal memory or control structures in ways that previous versions do not understand or cannot cope with. Downgrades may potentially be destructive as a result and lose or corrupt your data.

Answer (score 1):

I would heartily recommend begging or borrowing a Windows machine, honestly.

I had a very similar issue with Mac & eventually gave in to the fact that to achieve this I would need to put it in a PC as an internal (but not boot) drive, format NTFS, run the then simple update & drop it back to the Mac to start afresh.

After days of fighting the intransigent Mac command line tools, it took half an hour, most of that being the format & cloning.

Answer (score -1):

Do you think this will apply using a bootable usb with freedos?
https://gms.tf/updating-samsung-ssd-firmware-in-the-21st-century.html

Comment: -1 from me. While this link may be useful in this case, your answer is a question rather than an answer and I've almost automatically flagged it as "not an answer". Other users may ignore it too. Also, answers should be self-contained so that they're immune to link rot. You can fix your answer by [edit]ing it, I'll retract my vote.